# Internet explorer script error when loading jstree

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I have been using the jstree in my project and the problem i face now is when the json data for that particular node is more than 200 the tree hangs and a script error is shown in IE.

What I am doing now is creating the ul and li elements manually and pushing into DOM this seems to solve the problem. But I want to know Is there any other way to solve this large tree problem?

Comment: Sigh. I just spent several minutes typing up an answer to another question you just deleted. That's damned frustrating.

Comment: @sarnold: i am sorry man already 5 to 10 have voted for a close. thats why i deleted it.

Comment: @sarnold: do you know the answer?

Comment: No, only a few had voted for a close. If it _had_ been five, it would have been closed already. I know nothing about IE, but I knew a lot about starting services at boot.

Comment: @sarnold: Thanks for replying. yeah i am not asking abt this issue. I have posted the same question in http://askubuntu.com/questions/79107/how-to-run-a-ubuntu-script-at-startup

Comment: what script error is shown (details)? which IE version did you test?